# Proof that any finite subset of a lattice has a supremum.

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $C\subseteq D$ where $C = \{c_{1}, c_{2},\ldots, c_{n}\}$ and $D$ is a lattice. I believe that this supremum is $((c_1 \vee c_2)\vee c_3)\vee \ldots \vee c_n)$ (sorry about the notation). However I cannot prove that this is the supremum, I tried assuming it wasn't but couldn't find a contradiction. All help is welcome, thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proceed by induction on $n$ to prove that $s = (\ldots(((c_1 \vee c_2) \vee c_3) \vee \ldots \vee c_n)$ is indeed the supremum.  We know that in the case of $n = 1$, $s = c_1$ is a supremum of $n$.

Now assume true for all values $< n$.  Then by definition of the meet (which is denoted by $\vee$) we have that $s \geq c_i$ for every $i$.  Now, suppose $a \geq c_i$ for every $i$.  Define $b = c_1 \vee c_2 \vee \ldots \vee c_{n-1}$; by the inductive hypothesis, $b$ is the supremum of $\{c_i\}_{i = 1}^{n-1}$, so we have $a \geq b$.  Now, since $a \geq b$ and $a \geq c_n$, we have that $a \geq b \vee c_n$ by definition of the meet.  But $b \vee c_n = s$, so we have $a \geq s$, i.e. $s$ is a supremum.

Answer (score 4):

This proof is really a template of a proof, that you have certainly seen before, and will see again.

If $A$ is a collection of sets and $*$ is an associative binary operation on $A$, then $*$ can be extended to any finite sequence of elements. If $*$ is also commutative and idempotent (in the sense that $a*a=a$), then $*$ can be extended to finite *subsets* of $A$.

This is simply by induction, where the fact $*$ is well-defined for two means you can extend it further.

You have probably seen this in the proof of DeMorgan law extended to any finite number of sets; and you may have seen this in the proof that any finite intersection of open sets is open; and you probably saw this in the proof that a finite union of finite sets is a finite set; and you may have seen this in other places through mathematics.

In this case, you use the fact that taking supremum is well-defined for two elements; it is associative and commutative, and in fact idempotent ($a\lor a=a$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I did not prove that $\vee$ is an associative operation.

Comment: That's actually pretty easy to prove.

Comment: Actually, the claim that you are trying to prove already implies associativity. Since the order of the elements of a set does not matter, and the supremum is, or should be, well-defined regardless to the order of the elements. This means essentially that $(c_1\lor c_2)\lor c_3)=(c_2\lor c_3)\lor c_1=c_1\lor(c_2\lor c_3)$.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, proving my claim implies in proving associativity, right?

Comment: Yes. But you can prove associativity directly anyway from the definition of supremum.

Comment: Would you bother to give me a proof? Because before asking here I saw that my claim implied in associativity and tried to prove it, but I failed.

Comment: Let $a=(c_1\lor c_2)\lor c_3$ and $b=c_1\lor(c_2\lor c_3)$. By definition $c_1,(c_2\lor c_3)\leq b$, therefore $c_1,c_2\leq b$, therefore $c_1\lor c_2\leq b$ (by definition of supremum); but also $c_3\leq(c_2\lor c_3)\leq b$, therefore $(c_1\lor c_2)\lor c_3\leq b$. Meaning $a\leq b$. The other direction is similar, so $a\leq b\leq a$ and so $a=b$.