# Prove that every non-empty finite subset of a lattice has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Suppose $(P,\leq)$ is a generic lattice. Then for every $\{a,b\}$ in the relation $ \leq $, the set of its upper bounds is not empty and has a least element, and the set of its lower bounds is not empty and has a least element.

Suppose $ S $ is a non-empty subset of the lattice. Two cases arise:

we can denote the upper bounds and lower bounds of a set with $u(S)$ and $ l(S)$ respectively

if $\{a,b\}$ is included in $ S $, then $u(S)   $ is included in $ u(\{a,b \})$ since if $x$ is in  $u(S)   $, then it is true that $ a \leq x$ and $ b \leq x$. But since $ u(\{a,b \})$ has least element, every set included in it also has a least element, therefore there is a least upper bound also in $ u(S)$

The reasoning for the lower bound is analoguous.

I do not understand how to prove it for  { a } included in { a,b }.
Could you possibly give me some hint on how to proceed with the solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your reasoning for the set $S$ is not correct. Suppose that $a,b \in S$, but also $c=a\vee b \in S$. The fact that there is a least element in $u(\{a,b\})$, which is $c$, doesn't imply that $c$ is the least element of $u(S)$; actually, it may happen that $c<d \in S$, whence $c \notin u(S)$. So you have to try a different way; usually this is done by natural induction. I really don't understand the contents of the last paragraph.

Comment: @amrsa thanks, will try to use induction

Comment: There's an answer here: [Proof that any finite subset of a lattice has a supremum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1377071/303170)